# S3 presigned urls: PUT with Content-MD5 always fails

Tags: amazon-s3

It's not clear to me how to embed `Content-MD5` header when a make a `PUT` on my generated `presigned-url`. I mean:

I've request a PUT presigned-url to my service attaching an base64 encoded 128-bit md5 checksum:

```bash
$ md5sum hurl/push-document/lorem.txt                                                                                             1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82  hurl/push-document/lorem.txt
$ echo "1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82" | base64                                                                                MWQxMTQ2OWU5ZDgxZjA3NzI5NTQ4ZDc3MDhiYmFiODIK
```

I received a PUT presigned-url like this:

```
http://localstack.localhost:8000/espaidoc/7a11630d-41c8-4c6f-8a5f-7a1ad9d8841d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240304T062
413Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Credential=test%2F20240304%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0f4cd7986e292f
0eff51de7ffef7ff49132050c90fd2c6141baaf68764a000b2
```

When I make a PUT to just received `presigned-url`, I first add `Content-MD5` header I make the `PUT`:

```bash
$ curl --request PUT --header 'Content-MD5: MWQxMTQ2OWU5ZDgxZjA3NzI5NTQ4ZDc3MDhiYmFiODIK' --header 'Content-Type:' --data-binary '@hurl/push-document/lorem.txt' 'http://localstack.localhost:8000/espaidoc/f58e63f2-a075-46f2-b4fa-5e5d72776d1e?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240304T063920Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Credential=test%2F20240304%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=3ff0685e9f670562bcd241d5d1882ebbb49adbae9fd4110e45c65541ec35c1e7'
```

However, I'm getting an `InvalidDigest` code response:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Error><Code>InvalidDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.</Message><RequestId>aeffb976-4ac5-4b71-9512-d97b107a1eff</RequestId><Content-MD5>1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82</Content-MD5></Error>
```

I don't quite figure out what, I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to upload your file without Content-MD5 header and to check the ETag value created by AWS.

Comment: I don't quite figure out what do you suggest... Which is the difference?

Comment: If you run a simple `aws s3api put-object` it will return a etag containing the md5 checksum of the uploaded object as computed by AWS. Just suggesting to check you get the same value (ie. '1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82').